# How can I setup Respond for one site?

Tags: respondcms

For my next project I decided to use RespondCMS and there appears one 'small' problem and question: how can I setup system, to correctly work with only one site and have it on root domain? E.g.: on mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com/sites/site

Answer (score 0):

RespondCMS 5.3 & before is designed for building multiple websites hence the setup. What you are after sounds as though it will be found in Respond 6 yet this is in a beta testing stage at present. [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/respond-cms/ULZtzogoSGM) is some more info .....

ps Apache would be the answer pointing yourdomain.com to you site root but that can depend on your server setup & what control you have etc. Hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the domain to your root domain by using the Virtual Host setting in your server if you are using Apache.

This is an example of that if you are using something like LAMP

DocumentRoot "/var/www/respond/app/sites/your-site"
    ServerName yourdomain.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/respond/app/sites/your-site"
    ServerName www.yourdomain.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/respond/app"
    ServerName app.yourdomain.com